# Test Nginx vhost configuration

Tags: nginx

I know we can test nginx conf files with command line such as:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t
```

It there any similar way to test vhost files ? I tried

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/somesite.vhost -t
```

but it returns weird errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vhost file is usually not a complete configuration file and the test will therefore fail and return "weird errors".

However, if you have included the vhost files in your main configuration (with an `include` statement), the first test your wrote will also test all included files.

If you want to test the sub files separately, your best bet would be to write a minimal valid config file and include your test file in this.

Comment: well, I included  `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` but not sites-available in main nginx.conf . If I understood correctly you suggest to add a "fake" but valid conf file and include sites-available folder in it for test purpose only ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes, exactly...